# Call to undefined function import_request_variables()

Tags: php

Сервер с *PHP 5.3* перешел на *PHP 5.6* и перестал работать сайт.

Погуглила проблему и заменила везде в файлах `eregi` на `preg_match`

```
if (preg_match("mainfile.php",$PHP_SELF))
{
```

В итоге, выдает такую вот ошибку:

```
Call to undefined function import_request_variables()
```

и не работает. Подскажите, что делать.

Answer (score -1):

Замени `import_request_variables` на

```
extract($_POST);
extract($_GET);
```

или что вам там нужно за глобальные переменные.